# Laravel Livewire : Component keys not working unless uniqid() is used?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I got a `livewire` component like:

Component Class:

```
class TestComponent extends Component
{
    public $showFilter = true;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Handle : Filter Button Click
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public function handleFilterButtonClick() {

        $this->showFilter = !$this->showFilter;
    }
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Render
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.something');
    }
    
}
```

Blade File:

```
<div class="show-filter-btn" wire:click="handleFilterButtonClick">
    hide / show filters
</div>

<div class="some-div">

    @if($showFilter)
    
        @livewire('search.side-bar', key(uniqid()));
    
    @endif
    
</div>

<div style="flex-grow: 1"> {{-- ref={ function(element) { self._input = element; } } --}}

    <div>

        @livewire('search.pagination', [], key(uniqid()));
        
    </div>
        
</div>
```

when I clicked the `show-filter-btn` it will `show/hide` the `sidebar` component, I am using `uniqid()` to generate the `key()` for both `components` because if I use anything other than that ( Example: `abc-123123`, `sidebar-1234` etc ) it will throw the `index.js:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fingerprint' of null` error, I am new to `livewire`, so I do not quite understand how it works, the components are not next to each other, so why do they also need `unique` keys to identify each other? react only need keys when there is a `loop` and `list`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the same error, but I encountered something similar today whereby I had multiple components on the same blade file.  What I learned is that if I use `model->id` as the livewire $key for more than 1 of the components, livewire got bamboozled and couldn't tell the difference between index #1 for component A and index #1 for component B.  It seemed to lose track of which loop was applicable.

I ended up changing my code by concatenating a string identifier and the issue was resolved.

`key($account->id)` became `key('account-'.$account->id)`

and

`key($role->id)` became `key('role-'.$role->id)`

No longer were the key values colliding, thus solving the challenge.

Again, not sure if this is the same challenge you had, but close enough for me to put my 2 cents in.